# Flask application returns 400 bad request when accessed by device's ipv4 address but returns correctly on localhost

Tags: python, api, flask, networking, ipv4

My flask code is:

```py
@app.route('/get_all',methods=['GET'])
def get_all():
    cache=[]
    with open("filepath", newline='') as csvfile:
        reader=csv.reader(csvfile,dialect='excel')
        for row in reader:
            cache.append(row)
    return jsonify(cache)
```

and when I run ipv4_address:5000/get_all I receive:

> 172.30.211.33 - - [21/May/2021 11:18:45] code 400, message Bad request version ('**\x13\x01\x13\x02\x13\x03À+À/À,À0Ì©Ì¨À\x13À\x14\x00\x9c\x00\x9d\x00/\x005\x01\x00\x01\x93JJ\x00\x00\x00\x17\x00\x00ÿ\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00')

However, when I run localhost:5000/get_all I receive:

> 127.0.0.1 - - [21/May/2021 11:18:57] "GET /get_all HTTP/1.1" 200 -

and the browser correctly returns the requested JSON. ICMP is unblocked and I am using

```py
app.run(host="0.0.0.0",port=5000)
```

So I am unsure how to proceed. Does anyone have experience with a similar problem to this?

UPDATE SOLUTION: I changed https://ipv4_address... to http://ipv4_address which fixed the issue and now it is returning correctly over the local network.

Comment: what do you use as `ipv4_address` ? What do you use to access this page? Do you use `http` or `https` ?

Comment: 172.30.211.33 is the address

Comment: oh my lord changing it from https://... to http://... actually fixed it wow. I never would have thought it was something so simple

Comment: if you use `https` then browser sends it encrypted and you would need something more to encrypt it.

Comment: Ah that makes sense thank you